# Break sub-routine on Excel button while Excel is locked in procedure

Tags: excel, vba, break

I have written a VBA procedure (initiated in Excel 2010) which loops around an array containing different Excel files. The loop opens the file, refreshes the data, saves and closes the file for each item in the array. The process can take up to 90 minutes to complete, so I wanted a safe break routine which will stop the process when the current iteration is complete.

I contained the code in a do-while loop with a boolean initialized to False. I created a Stop button in Excel which sets the boolean variable to True when pressed so the do while condition will be met and stop the procedure.

The stop button is based in the same excel file which initializes the procedure of opening and closing excel files. *This means that the excel instance locks, so a user cannot press the break button and halt the procedure.*

How can I access the stop button? Or is there an alternative way to initiate the break?

My Code - Added 06/06/2014 15:12

```
Sub Refresh_Weekly()
failedIndex = 0
'DoEvents
'Refresh_StandardWeekly ' module 2
'Refresh_NonStandardWeekly ' module 4
Refresh_CRIS ' module 3

If StopMsg <> "" Then
    MsgBox StopMsg

    ElseIf failedIndex = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All Weekly Pivots refreshed"
    Else
        For x = 0 To failedIndex - 1
        OutputMsg = OutputMsg + Failed(x) & ", "
        Next x
    MsgBox "Pivots which failed to refresh:" & OutputMsg
End If
Erase Failed
OutputMsg = ""
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Refresh_CRIS()

Dim routepath As String
routepath = "\\nch\dfs\SharedArea\Private\BIS\Groups\KPI-Group\Pivots\"

ChDir routepath

Dim CRISPiv As Variant 'Includes Dailies
Dim i
Dim errorText As String
Dim x
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
Ref = True

CRISPiv = Array("Waiting-List-Diagnostic.xls", "Cancer_PTL Position.xls")

Do While Ref
DoEvents

For Each i In CRISPiv
    If File_Exists(routepath & i) Then
        If isFileOpen(i) = True Then
        errorText = i
        Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
        failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
        Else

        objXL.Visible = False
        objXL.Workbooks.Open Filename:=routepath & i
            If objXL.ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then
            objXL.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            objXL.Application.CalculateFull
            objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Save
            objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            objXL.Quit

            Else
            errorText = i
            Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
            failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
            objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            objXL.Quit
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
    errorText = i
    Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
    failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
    End If

Next i
Ref = False
Loop

Unload UserForm1

Exit Sub

Resume Next

End Sub
```

---

```
Public RefStop As Boolean
Public StopMsg As String

Sub Refresh_Stop_Test_Click()

Ref = False
StopMsg = "Refresh Cancelled"

End Sub
```

---

A highly altered version of my code is below to try and match @David's code as best I could and it still doesn't work. I needed to add boo = False after my For each statement finishes otherwise it would loop to infinity. I also added a simple msgbox to test if the button works. Everything else is the same but the form won't allow me to press the button. If I press where the button is multiple times (think frustrated mega clicking) when the code finishes and pops up with the "Fine" msg it beeps that number of times so it obviously isn't dealing with my input.

Code:

Public boo As Boolean

```
Sub Refresh_CRIS()

Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Dim i, CRISPiv
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

CRISPiv = Array("C:/Temp/test/Book1.xlsm", "C:/Temp/test/Book2.xlsm")
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

boo = True

Do While boo
    DoEvents
    For Each i In CRISPiv
        objXL.Visible = False
        objXL.Workbooks.Open i
        objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Save
        objXL.Quit
    Next
boo = False

Loop

Unload UserForm1
If StopMsg <> "" Then
MsgBox StopMsg

Else: MsgBox "Fine"
End If
```

### End Sub

Dropbox link to my Excel control file:

[Excel Control file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n0jec8h0edftur6/AADlRnvnzuSpYMNvMUxwORRva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from your code:

```
Public ref As Boolean
Sub Refresh_CRIS()
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

Dim routepath As String
routepath = "\\nch\dfs\SharedArea\Private\BIS\Groups\KPI-Group\Pivots\"

ChDir routepath
'
Dim CRISPiv As Variant 'Includes Dailies
Dim i
Dim errorText As String
Dim x
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
ref = True

CRISPiv = Array("Waiting-List-Diagnostic.xls", "Cancer_PTL Position.xls")
For Each i In CRISPiv
    If File_Exists(routepath & i) Then
        If isFileOpen(i) = True Then
        errorText = i
        Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
        failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
        Else
        objXL.Visible = False
        objXL.Workbooks.Open Filename:=routepath & i
            If objXL.ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then
            objXL.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            objXL.Application.CalculateFull
            objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Save
            objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            objXL.Quit

            Else
            errorText = i
            Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
            failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
            objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            objXL.Quit
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
    errorText = i
    Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
    failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
    End If

DoEvents
If ref = False Then
Exit For
End If
Next i

Unload UserForm1
Debug.Print ref 'put this in to see how the code is exiting
Exit Sub

Errorhandler:

errorText = i
Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
failedIndex = failedIndex + 1

Resume Next
End Sub
```

Moved your `DoEvents` to the end of the for loop as it was not functioning at all where it wa. This way as well it will at least go through the full routine and not cause potential errors further down the line with partially refreshed data on your existing sheets.

It is tested working now

Comment: No joy. I had to put another DoEvents call in at the top of the For loop, otherwise the userform doesn't build fully. If I click the button it changes the message at the end (Refresh cancelled) but the 2nd file still opens and refreshes instead of ending the procedure. Is there a reason you removed the Do While loop - it seems as though this would be needed?

Comment: Could it be that it doesn't process the button click until after it has checked the Do while condition before it opens the 2nd file? So if I had three files but clicked it early in the process it would work? I'll try and test that. Alternatively if I put the do while inside my For loop it would check the condition before opening 2nd file? Few things for me to test

Comment: Okay so i'm fairly confident the issue is that the code enters the For loop and doesn't check my stop condition until it has finished with each file in the array(CRISPiv). So it won't stop the process but does register the click after it finishes. If I put the do while inside the for loop i can stop the process with the button but I can't iterate i so it keeps opening the same file until i press the stop button. So I think I need a way to keep the process running in my for loop until my stop condition = True. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: If it is not generating the form, try a DoEvents BEFORE the For loop. It should load the form OK then. The Do while was confusing matters in the code as it wasnt needed. Your For Next is the only loop you need. And the code I have written will only stop the event once it has finished with the current file. It wont stop half way through it. If you did want it to stop half way through, you would need to add the `DoEvents... If/End If` after each of the `objExcel.` calls although that could get a whole lot messier as you then have hidden sheets open in the background only killable by Task Manager

Comment: And the `Exit For` in the If section will exit that For Next loop as soon as its detected, so should be absolutely no reason that part 2 was loaded unless Part 1 was already complete (you would be surprised how quick some smaller files will refresh. I run 15 reports in the background like that nightly and some take a matter of 2-3 seconds to open, refresh and close). If visible, they can take a minute or so. Big difference.

Comment: Okay, I'll try the DoEvents before the for loop tomorrow and remove the do while again. I deliberatly picked files that don't open, refresh and close quickly so I would have time to close when testing. I was hitting almost as soon as it was opening as part of my testing to and no joy. Hopefully the DoEvents change will fix it. Speak to you tomorrow - thanks for your efforts, this one has gone on a while!

Comment: Right, your efforts to get my break routine working have succeeded. Thank you very much! The only wrinkle is when i have scaled the process up. There are a total of 80 different reports which need to be refreshed in different locations. I have been gradually adding sections in but I keep getting dialog boxes popping up with the message: _Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action._ It does eventually run but its taking an awful long time. The file causing the error is quite large. Is this issue something I can fix or do i just need to hide the message

Comment: Yeah I would just handle that. Should be do-able with an `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` around the whole thing. Sounds like its basically just waiting for the newly created instance of Excel to complete and close before continuing.

Comment: Yeah I was trying that but made the mistake of turning off the alerts in the wrong instance, it's now working. I have a lingering issue with a slightly more complex refresh block but i'll post it as a seperate question as this is creeping along too long. Cheers for all your help @bmgh1985

Comment: No problem @SliderSteve. Glad we got there eventually! If youre having refresh errors, you may want to try eliminating the refreshall method for a `For Each...` loop running `querytable.refresh (false)` for each sheet. The false stops it doing it in the background and will wait for the refresh before continuing... quite often the cause of errors with not fully refreshed data due to the code carrying on regardless.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a hack but you can write

`VBA.DoEvents`

in your tight loop. Basically this waits for the user interface event queue to flush. This will allow you to click the stop button, handle its event and set the appropriate boolean flag.

Comment: "a bit of a hack" describes many aspects of working with VBA doesn't it?

Comment: It is not really a *hack,* just a way of sharing focus between the macro and the user.

Comment: Can also use a counter + mod check to only yield once every *n* loops.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not have it create a new instance of excel for running each file? Would leave your main instance freed up and would mean that you could essentially click the button any time (provided it was on a non-modal form - or is it modal? Always get them mixed up :P) and it would complete the one it was on in its own instance and not carry on with the rest of the loop.

EDIT: Here is an example excel file: http://we.tl/Hcfce2PnWv

Comment: This is better solution, I think. Unless there is some *need* to open the files in the same instance of Excel (and that seems unlikely), open them in a new instance, keep that instance `.Visible = False`, and have a userform (`.Show vbModeless`) running in the main instance.

Comment: I managed to get the code to open and close the excel files in my array in a separate instance but the control instance is still locked to user interaction.

Comment: The interface I designed to control the procedure is extremely simple - I drew some boxes with the drawing tool and assigned my code to work when the box is clicked. Do you think this is my problem? David, you mentioned creating a userform, would this actually get around the problem or is it just an alternative interface?

Comment: @DavidZemens I built a simple user form to test it out but `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` leaves the form unusable whilst the code runs. The form doesn't even populate with my button until teh code finishes, at which point I can interact with it. Leaving it set as modal shows the form but doesn't run the code until i close the form.

Comment: @SliderSteve Have added an example file to my answer that works on my machine. Give it a go and see if it works OK for you (adds a 1 to each cell in column A until you click or it gets to 100)

Answer (score 1):

Example of userform:

In normal code module:

```
Public boo As Boolean
Sub Test()
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Dim i, CRISPiv
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

CRISPiv = Array("C:/users/david_zemens/desktop/Book2.xlsx", "C:/users/david_zemens/desktop/vacation planning.xlsm")
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

boo = True
'infinite loop

Do While boo
    DoEvents
    For Each i In CRISPiv
        objXL.Visible = False
        objXL.Workbooks.Open i
        objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        objXL.Quit   
    Next

Loop

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

In userform module assign this to the button's _Click event handler, just set `boo` to False.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
boo = False
End Sub
```

The procedure `Test` is an infinite loop that only terminates of `boo = False`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for replying again @David. I tested your code example and of course it worked. It was very similar to my current structure. I have applied it to my logic, the userform is now visible but still won't accept user input. When you try to click the button it doesn't register. I would normally post my code in this situation but it won't fit in the comments box - any suggestions?

Comment: You can make a revision to your original question, just include the code you're currently using in the Q and I can take a look at it in a little while.

Comment: Thanks @David, bit slow there. I figured that out eventually and actually posted it while you were replying. I really appreciate your time

Comment: I was actually looking at this myself and discovered it was causing me the same problem where it wouldnt kick me out of the loop with a similar example (only difference being a false boolean and Loop until). Will see if I can find another way.

Comment: Instead of having a boolean trigger in the `CommandButton1_Click`, can you try a slightly dirtier method? Just type in `End` in place of anything else and let me know if it stops the code (will however stop it in place rather than exiting neatly at the end of a loop)

Comment: If it does then we know your Userform is working OK. It doesnt seem to like passing the boolean though (on mine as well, assuming you are having a similar problem)

Comment: No, it won't allow me to press the button so it doesn't matter what code I put in there unfortunately. Nice try

Comment: I just changed my DoEvents placement to the end of the looping code and it worked fine then. Dont know if it will make a difference, but maybe add some more `DoEvents` throughout the code and try it then (its not going to hurt at least)

Comment: Peppering my code with DoEvents didn't solve it unfortunately.

Comment: I updated mye xample to more closely represent the workings of @SliderSteve's loop, I still am able to interact with the form while the macro procedes to open files in the loop.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have updated my question to include my attempt to alter my code to match yours but it still doesn't work. This is bizarre.

Comment: Can you possible strip out all of the *data* in your Excel file, and upload it to Google Docs or Dropbox? I want to see what happens if I try to run the macro.

Comment: I took out the real excel files and replaced them with dummy ones which didn't contain anything, then added a delay so they stayed open long enough to test the procedure. I still couldn't get the userform to unlock. So if I sent you the files now then they would just be blank excel files? Unless you mean my control Excel file?

Comment: I don't need the files that are being processed, I just want to try and run tthe `Refresh_CRIS` procedure from your file and see if it exhibits the same unexpected behavior.

Comment: Okay that's no problem. There's no data in there. Unfortunately I can't access dropbox, google drive etc as i'm behind a work firewall! I have e-mailed it home and will upload it when I get back. Sorry but I won't be back for a bit so there will be a delay. Thanks very much for the offer, I'll update you as soon as I can.

Comment: No worries, I'm actually putting out fires today at work so probably I can't look at it until later tonight or tomorrow anyways!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had a few problems this weekend. I have added a dropbox link to the bottom of my question which contains the my Excel file that controls the process. Thanks for agreeing to take a look @DavidZemens

Comment: @SliderSteve Just looking at this as well. At first glance, there is no check in place in the `For` loop, which is where it needs to be. In this, it checks if a user cancels before the files start and then once all files have been processed. Also, ref is not declared anywhere as a public variable from what I can see and it needs to be otherwise you cannot cross-reference the variable and it will never exit.

Comment: Thanks @bmgh1985 ref was declared but I changed a few thinsg before I uploaded it (used to be called refStop) - I changed the variable name locally and also placed a DoEvents call in the For loop but it didnt fix the issue. I will alter the file to suit above

Comment: I'll test it out, thanks very much @bmgh1985 . I had worked out that placing my public variable declarations next to the code for my userform was also causing a problem. I have no idea why. Once i moved them to my main module the variables seemed to update but code didnt break. I will check back in an hour (hopefully with a positive response to your edits!!!) Cheers